# Shortening this simple code in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQEPe.jpg

As you can see on the picture, I have a stupidly long code, just to get the information I want in the Comboboxes. Is there any way to make it so I dont need that long of a code?

The comboboxes should display the same information, yet be able to record different "results"
Im obviously a beginner programmer. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create an array with the data you need, for example:

```
var dataArray:Array = [{label:"label1", data:"data1"}, {label:"label2", data:"data2"}];//as many objects as you need.
```

then name the dropdown lists and use the "dataProvider" property to populate it:

```
dropdown1.dataProvider = new DataProvider(dataArray);
dropdown2.dataProvider = new DataProvider(dataArray);
dropdown3.dataProvider = new DataProvider(dataArray);
....
```

P.S. don't forget to import:

```
import fl.data.DataProvider;
```